# How to write multiple queries in one query based on condition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    [LNMAJORTP], [MainType],
    SUM(x + y - z) [x]
FROM 
    [my_table]  
WHERE 
    state LIKE '%firstCondition%'
GROUP BY
    [LNMAJORTP], [MainType] 

SELECT 
    [LNMAJORTP], [MainType],
    SUM(x + y - z) [y]
FROM 
    [my_table]  
WHERE 
    state LIKE '%secondCondition%'
GROUP BY
    [LNMAJORTP], [MainType] 

SELECT 
    [LNMAJORTP], [MainType],
    SUM(x + y - z) [z]
FROM 
    [my_table]  
WHERE
    state LIKE '%thirdCondition%'
GROUP BY
    [LNMAJORTP], [MainType]
```

How I can change this queries to one query?

Comment: Isn't this to be achieved through OR: `WHERE state LIKE '%firstCondition%' OR state LIKE '%secondCondition%' OR state LIKE '%thirdCondition%'`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sum your expressions and get results in three different columns (`[x]`, `[y]` and `[z]`), use next approach.

```
SELECT 
    [LNMAJORTP],
    [MainType],
    SUM(CASE WHEN state LIKE '%firstCondition%' THEN x+y-z END) AS [x],
    SUM(CASE WHEN state LIKE '%secondCondition%' THEN x+y-z END) AS [y],
    SUM(CASE WHEN state LIKE '%thirdCondition%' THEN x+y-z END) AS [z]
FROM [my_table] 
GROUP BY [LNMAJORTP], [MainType]
```

If you want to sum just one expression (`x+y-z` in your example), simple `OR` in `WHERE` clause should work. The result of the expression will be in one column:

```
SELECT 
    [LNMAJORTP],
    [MainType],
    SUM(x+y-z) AS [x_y_z]
FROM [my_table] 
WHERE state LIKE '%firstCondition%' OR state LIKE '%secondCondition%' OR state LIKE '%thirdCondition%'
GROUP BY [LNMAJORTP], [MainType]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge your three query as follow. Which will return your results in different rows-

```
SELECT state,[LNMAJORTP],[MainType],
sum(x+y-z) [z]
FROM [my_table]  
where state LIKE '%thirdCondition%'
OR state LIKE '%firstCondition%'
OR state LIKE '%secondCondition%'
GROUP BY state,[LNMAJORTP],[MainType]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a UNION ALL between each select.

```
SELECT 
    [LNMAJORTP], [MainType],
    SUM(x + y - z) [x]
FROM 
    [my_table]  
WHERE 
    state LIKE '%firstCondition%'
GROUP BY
    [LNMAJORTP], [MainType] 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    [LNMAJORTP], [MainType],
    SUM(x + y - z) [y]
FROM 
    [my_table]  
WHERE 
    state LIKE '%secondCondition%'
GROUP BY
    [LNMAJORTP], [MainType] 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    [LNMAJORTP], [MainType],
    SUM(x + y - z) [z]
FROM 
    [my_table]  
WHERE
    state LIKE '%thirdCondition%'
GROUP BY
    [LNMAJORTP], [MainType]
```